# create 2 buttons to initialize 2 models when they are clicked

Tags: android

I want to create 2 buttons : when I click to button1 the model1 is initialized and when I click on button2 the model2 is initialized so I created new activity (MainSecond.java) where I created the 2 buttons and send their ids to MainActivity where the 2 models initialized 
the problem is when I click on any of the two buttons the 2 models are initialized 
 this is my code :

MainSecond.java

```
public  class MainSecond extends Activity {
public Button button1;
public Button button2;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_main);


    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            BackToMain(R.id.button1);
          //  BackToMain(view);

        }
    });

    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            BackToMain(R.id.button1);

        }

    });
}


public void BackToMain(int button_id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainSecond.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("name",button_id);
    intent.putExtra("name",button_id);
    startActivity(intent);


}
```

**MainActivity.java**

initialization of 2 models

```
 public class InitializeModelAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            final boolean ret = DeeplabModel.initialize();
             Logger.debug("initialize deeplab model: %s", ret);
                return ret;
        }
    }



   public class InitializeModelAsyncTask2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        final boolean ret2 = DeeplabModel2.initialize();
        Logger.debug("initialize deeplab model: %s", ret2);

            return ret2;

    }
}
```

getting buttons ids :

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buckyButton = findViewById(R.id.buckysButton);


       //  src_img =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.src_img) ;

       Intent mIntent=getIntent();
        int intval=mIntent.getIntExtra("buttonid",0);
        if(intval==R.id.button1){

            initModel();

        }

        if(intval==R.id.button2){

            initModel2();
        }
```

}

```
 private void syncUIWithPermissions(boolean requestIfNeed) {
    final boolean granted = checkRequiredPermissions(requestIfNeed);
       setPickImageEnabled(granted);
       setPickImageEnabled2(granted);

           if (granted && !DeeplabModel.isInitialized()) {
               initModel();
           }

      else if (granted && !DeeplabModel2.isInitialized()) {
            initModel2();
        }

    }


private boolean checkRequiredPermissions() {
    return checkRequiredPermissions(false);
}

private boolean checkRequiredPermissions(boolean requestIfNeed) {
    final boolean writeStoragePermGranted =
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

    Logger.debug("storage permission granted: %s", writeStoragePermGranted);

    if (!writeStoragePermGranted
            && requestIfNeed) {
        requestRequiredPermissions();
    }

    return writeStoragePermGranted;
}

private void requestRequiredPermissions() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            },
            REQUEST_REQUIRED_PERMISSION);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Logger.debug("requestCode = 0x%02x, permission = [%s], grant = [%s]",
            requestCode,
            ArrayUtils.stringArrayToString(permissions, ","),
            ArrayUtils.intArrayToString(grantResults));
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_REQUIRED_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Logger.debug("permission granted, initialize model.");
            initModel();
            initModel2();
```

}

the initMode() and intitModel2() functions are :

```
private void initModel() {
    new InitializeModelAsyncTask().execute((Void)null);
}
private void initModel2() {
    new InitializeModelAsyncTask2().execute((Void)null);
}
```

this is the code that is used to show the 2 models on the screen

```
public class SegmentBitmapsLoader extends AbsAsyncDataLoader<List<SegmentBitmap>> {

private Uri mImageUri;


public SegmentBitmapsLoader(Context context, Uri imageUri) {
    super(context);

    mImageUri = imageUri;
}



@Nullable
    @Override

    public List<SegmentBitmap> loadInBackground() {
        final Context context = getContext();

        if (context == null) {
            return null;
        }

        final Resources res = context.getResources();

        if (res == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (mImageUri == null) {
            return null;
        }

        final String filePath = FilePickUtils.getPath(context, mImageUri);
        Logger.debug("file to mask: %s", filePath);
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filePath)) {
            return null;
        }

        boolean vertical = checkAndReportDimen(filePath);

        final int dw = res.getDimensionPixelSize(
                vertical ? R.dimen.image_width_v : R.dimen.image_width_h);
        final int dh = res.getDimensionPixelSize(
                vertical ? R.dimen.image_height_v : R.dimen.image_height_h);
        Logger.debug("display image dimen: [%d x %d]", dw, dh);

        Bitmap bitmap = decodeBitmapFromFile(filePath, dw, dh);
        if (bitmap == null) {
            return null;
        }


        List<SegmentBitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();

        bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_original, bitmap));//important note

        final int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        final int h = bitmap.getHeight();
        Logger.debug("decoded file dimen: [%d x %d]", w, h);

        EventBus.getDefault().post(new ImageDimenEvent(mImageUri, w, h));

        float resizeRatio = (float) DeeplabModel.INPUT_SIZE / Math.max(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        float resizeRatio2 = (float) DeeplabModel2.INPUT_SIZE / Math.max(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());


        int rw = Math.round(w * resizeRatio);
        int rh = Math.round(h * resizeRatio);

        int rw2 = Math.round(w * resizeRatio2);
        int rh2 = Math.round(h * resizeRatio2);

        Logger.debug("resize bitmap: ratio = %f, [%d x %d] -> [%d x %d]",
                resizeRatio, w, h, rw, rh);
        Logger.debug("resize bitmap: ratio = %f, [%d x %d] -> [%d x %d]",
                resizeRatio2, w, h, rw2, rh2);

        Bitmap resized = ImageUtils.tfResizeBilinear(bitmap, rw, rh);
        Bitmap resized2 = ImageUtils.tfResizeBilinear(bitmap, rw2, rh2);


        Bitmap mask = DeeplabModel.segment(resized);
        Bitmap mask2 = DeeplabModel2.segment(resized2);


        if (mask != null) {
            mask = BitmapUtils.scaleBitmap(mask, w, h);
            bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_mask, mask));

            final Bitmap cropped = cropBitmapWithMask(bitmap, mask);
            bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_cropped, cropped));
        }
        else {
            bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_mask, (Bitmap) null));
            bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_cropped, (Bitmap) null));

        }
    if(mask2 != null){
        mask2 = BitmapUtils.scaleBitmap(mask2, w, h);
        bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_mask, mask2));

        final Bitmap cropped = cropBitmapWithMask(bitmap, mask2);
        bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_cropped, cropped));
    }
    else {
        bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_mask, (Bitmap)null));
        bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_cropped, (Bitmap)null));

    }

        return bitmaps;


    }

    private boolean checkAndReportDimen(String filePath) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filePath)) {
            return false;
        }

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        final int width = options.outWidth;
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        Logger.debug("original image dimen: %d x %d", width, height);

        EventBus.getDefault().post(new ImageDimenEvent(mImageUri, width, height));

        return (height > width);
    }


    private Bitmap cropBitmapWithMask(Bitmap original, Bitmap mask) {
        if (original == null
                || mask == null) {
            return null;
        }

        final int w = original.getWidth();
        final int h = original.getHeight();
        if (w <= 0 || h <= 0) {
            return null;
        }

        Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cropped);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(null);

        return cropped;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeBitmapFromFile(String filePath,
                                              int reqWidth,
                                              int reqHeight) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filePath)) {
            return null;
        }

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

}

Comment: What is DeepLabModel.initialize() method doing?

Comment: this function take the model file and image and send them to tensorflow frame work in order to make image segmentation

Comment: the 2 models are  working very well but I cant separate between them with button click

Comment: I still have the same problem @vivekverma

Answer (score 0):

Well you are sending the same button id for both the buttons...
When you call BacktoMain method for both the buttons you are sending button1 id.

Change the line inside button2.onClickListener from

```
BackToMain(R.id.button1);
```

to

```
BackToMain(R.id.button2);
```

Do this...

```
public void BackToMain(int button_id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainSecond.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("name",button_id);
    intent.putExtra("name",button_id); //remove this line y do the same thing twice
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And...

```
Intent mIntent=getIntent();
        int intval=mIntent.getIntExtra("name",0);
              //should give you the button id and returns 0 if                  
              //value for the key "name" was not given
        if(intval==R.id.button1){
            initModel();
        }

        if(intval==R.id.button2){
            initModel2();
        }
```

Try these changes and lemme know if it works..

Comment: How can I fix this ?

Comment: Sorry but it gives me error  because of : getIntentExtra  ("name");

Comment: made some changes. plz check

Comment: Now there is no error in getIntentExtra("name") but the 2 models still initialized at the same time

Comment: I tried something but I don't know how to manage or link it with button click what I did is : I cleared  else if statement  in syncUIWithPermissions () and only the the first model appeared

Comment: I tried to make something like that if (granted &&!DeeplabModel.intialize  ()&&intvat==R.Id. button1)  but it gives me an error in intval

Comment: I will put the code that is responsible for displaying the two models on the screen